# How to role check with Role Reaction & Auto remove user Reaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hey I've gotten my role reaction so far but would like to make it so that after pressing the emoji the code asks if someone already has the group or not and accordingly adds or removes the group but I would also like to make it so that the reaction with the emoji is removed automatically so that only the bot reacts to the message that emoji is displayed.

I will add the code I have written so far in the attachment and maybe there are some people who can help me.

**MessageReactionAddEvent:**

```js
const BaseEvent = require('../utils/structures/BaseEvent');
require('dotenv').config();
module.exports = class MessageReactionAddEvent extends BaseEvent {
  constructor() {
    super('messageReactionAdd');
  }
  
  async run(client, reaction, user) {
    const message = reaction.message;
    const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);

    if(user.bot) return;
 
    const Valorant = message.guild.roles.cache.get(process.env.DISCORD_ROLE_VALORANT);
    const League = message.guild.roles.cache.get(process.env.DISCORD_ROLE_LEAGUE);

    if(
      ["", ""].includes(reaction.emoji.name)
  ) {
      switch(reaction.emoji.name) {

          case"":
          if (message.member.roles.cache.has(process.env.DISCORD_ROLE_VALORANT)) {
            console.log('Has Valorant')
          } else {
            member.roles.add(Valorant)
            member.createDM().then( channel => {
                channel.send("Added Valorant")
            })
          }
          
          break;

          case"":
          if (message.member.roles.cache.has(process.env.DISCORD_ROLE_LEAGUE)) {
            console.log('Has League of Legends')
          } else {
            member.roles.add(League)
            member.createDM().then( channel => {
                channel.send("Added League of Legends")
            })
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**MessageReactionRemoveEvent:**

```js
const BaseEvent = require('../utils/structures/BaseEvent');
require('dotenv').config();
module.exports = class MessageReactionRemoveEvent extends BaseEvent {
  constructor() {
    super('messageReactionRemove');
  }
  
  async run(client, reaction, user) {
    const message = reaction.message;
    const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);

    if(user.bot) return;
 
    const Valorant = message.guild.roles.cache.get(process.env.DISCORD_ROLE_VALORANT);
    const League = message.guild.roles.cache.get(process.env.DISCORD_ROLE_LEAGUE);
 
    if(
        ["", ""].includes(reaction.emoji.name)
    ) {
        switch(reaction.emoji.name) {
 
          case"":
          if (message.member.roles.cache.has(process.env.DISCORD_ROLE_VALORANT)) {
            member.roles.remove(Valorant)
            member.createDM().then( channel => {
                channel.send("Added Valorant")
            })
          } else {
            console.log('Hasn´t Valorant')
          }
          
          break;

          case"":
          if (message.member.roles.cache.has(process.env.DISCORD_ROLE_LEAGUE)) {
            member.roles.remove(League)
            member.createDM().then( channel => {
                channel.send("Added League of Legends")
            })
          } else {
            console.log('Hasn´t League of Legends')
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**RolesCommand:**

```js
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = class RolesCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('roles', 'Team', []);
  }

  run(client, message, args) {
    try {
      message.delete()

      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Test1")
      .setDescription("Test2")
      .setColor("#FCCF00")
      .setFooter("Test3")

      message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {
          await msg.react("")
          await msg.react("")
      })

  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
    } 
  }
}
```

*Thanks for all the help I get so far the community has already helped me very well - thanks for that.*

Comment: Does your bot has all correct permissions to add roles? Have you make sure you the user is below the bot in the hierarchy order so the bot can be able to add a role? Does your code give any errors?

Comment: yes, yes and no I also have Auto Role and this works fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*With a lot of research and a friend who helped me I have now got it right and hope I can help everyone else who has the same problem.*

**Role Check with Role Reaction:**

```js
- message.member.roles.cache.has(process.env.DISCORD_ROLE_VALORANT)
+ member.roles.cache.has(process.env.DISCORD_ROLE_VALORANT)
```

**Auto remove user Reaction:**

```js
const userReactions = message.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(user.id));
try {
    for (const reaction of userReactions.values()) {
        await reaction.users.remove(user.id);
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to remove reactions.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that running `reaction.remove();` before your `switch` statements should do the trick :)

Comment: Now it deletes all reactions but it should only delete the own reaction, not the reaction of the bot.

Comment: @NOXSYS where exactly did you put the reaction.remove ? Because there is a user.bot check that should not let bot reactions get through

Comment: @NOXSYS And this does remove the bot's reaction ? You might want to check whether the user variable is correct, and also what the reaction variable looks like

Comment: Yes it does, unfortunately, and I even believe that both variables are correct. But unfortunately I don't know what else to do :/